# How to trim a string return so my test passes?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following function

```
export const getDurationToShow = ({ nDays, descriptive }) => {
    const years: number = Math.floor(nDays / 365);
    const months: number = Math.floor((nDays % 365) / 30);
    const days: number = Math.floor((nDays % 365) % 30) || 0;
    if (!!descriptive) {
        return `
                ${years > 0 ? `${years} year${years > 1 ? 's' : ''},` : ''} 
                ${months > 0 ? ` ${months} month${months > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${days > 0 ? ' and' : ''}` : ''} 
                ${days > 0 ? `${days} days` : ''}
            `;
    }
```

which essentially just breaks down a number and transforms it into readable days.
The outcome for this function would be something like

```
countDays(2000)
// 2 years, 9 months and 0 days
```

My problem is that I am writing unit tests for it, and seems like it's considering the line breaks as part of the return, which is causing my test to fail.
[image]

So how can I fix it to get my test success? I am not sure if I should fix the function itself or the way I am writing the test.

```
const twoThousandDaysDescriptive = getDurationToShow({ nDays: 2000, descriptive: true });
expect(twoThousandDaysDescriptive).toBe('5 years, 5 months and 25 days');
```

Thanks

Comment: You must fix it in the function, cause `getDurationToShow` returns a string with break lines and extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New lines( line endings ) matter in template literals**

```
export const getDurationToShow = ({ nDays, descriptive }) => {
const years: number = Math.floor(nDays / 365);
const months: number = Math.floor((nDays % 365) / 30);
const days: number = Math.floor((nDays % 365) % 30) || 0;
if (!!descriptive) {
    return `${years > 0 ? `${years} year${years > 1 ? 's' : ''},` : ''} ${
      months > 0
        ? `${months} month${months > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${days > 0 ? 'and' : ''}`
        : ''
    } ${days > 0 ? `${days} days` : ''}`;
  }
};
```

> Its a good practice to format lengthier template literals as follows

```
if (!!descriptive) {
    const y = years > 0 ? `${years} year${years > 1 ? 's' : ''},` : '';
    const m =
      months > 0
        ? `${months} month${months > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${days > 0 ? 'and' : ''}`
        : '';
    const d = days > 0 ? `${days} days` : '';
    return `${y} ${m} ${d}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return the string in the right format you're expecting.

```
return `${years > 0 ? `${years} year${years > 1 ? 's' : ''},` : ''} ${months > 0 ? `${months} month${months > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${days > 0 ? 'and' : ''}` : ''} ${days > 0 ? `${days} days` : ''}`;
```

Comment: I cant due to lint rules that can't be ignored

Comment: What can't be ignored?

Comment: max-line-length. I know I can choose to skip it with // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length, but an internal rule at the company wont allow me to pass the build step disabling rules.

Comment: You could extract the content of each interpolated expression into an intermediate variable then concatenate those, as shown in @anjan's answer.